# select records in a table that are repeated twice using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple relation  table of `list_id` and `member_id`

```
+---------+--------+
|list_id | Member_id|
+---------+--------+
| 0001    | B002   |
| 0001    | B005   |
| 0002    | B002   |
| 0003    | B003   |
| 0004    | B005   |
| 0004    | B002   |
| 0007    | B002   |
+---------+--------+
```

I want to generate a query to select the `list_id` that contains 2 members only (repeated in the table twice)

What I've reached so far:

Using nested queries the inner query  to select all  `distinct list_ID`, the outer Query to select the `count`, but it's a query not a loop so I failed to get the count for every one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select list_id
from yourtable
group by list_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: okay , its another solution than that i expected , so could you tell me  how to make an operation on each row that ive extracted from a nested Query , something to replace the for loop logic

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "make an operation on each row".

Answer (score 3):

You need an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), in this case, `count`:

```
SELECT list_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY list_id
HAVING count(member_id) = 2
```